# nginx log analysis with goaccess

Tags: logging, nginx, log-analysis, goaccess

I want to parse and analyze the nginx logs with [goaccess](http://goaccess.prosoftcorp.com/) and take a report from the analyzed logs.
But, when I run the `zcat -f access.log.*.gz | goaccess -a -c` command, it gives me the following error :

```
GoAccess - version 0.5 - Jun 26 2012 04:30:08
An error has occurred
Error occured at: parser.c - process_log - 584
Message: No date format was found on your conf file.
```

I tried to add the line `date_format %D %T` to .goaccessrc file but I got another error which is:

```
GoAccess - version 0.5 - Jun 26 2012 04:30:08
An error has occurred
Error occured at: parser.c - process_log - 588
Message: No log format was found on your conf file.
```

I think it asks for the date and log formats that nginx uses. 
but I have no any date or log format in my nginx configuration.

Additionally, I've tried to use a previous version of goaccess(0.4.2 version) 
and the `zcat -f access.log.*.gz | goaccess -a -c` command works fine. 
it doesn't asks for any date or log format and i can view the goaccess menu and 
i can view any data that want.

But when I try to get a html report with `zcat -f access.log.*.gz | goaccess -a -c > report.html`
command, it does nothing. it just waits and waits.(without giving any warning or error)

Note: i've checked this webpages and if you want to take a look too.

1. http://goaccess.prosoftcorp.com/faq
2. http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLogModule

Comment: can you post a sample line from your access.log?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Got it working with the following `~/.goaccessrc`:

```
date_format %d/%b/%Y:%T %z
log_format %h - - [%d] "%r" %s %b "%R" "%u"
```

I installed GoAccess as a binary package from wheezy repository (no source recompilation).

Comment: and executing with goaccess -f [log_file] -p ~/.goaccessrc

Comment: this worked for me, but i also had to add --no-global-config at the command line.

Answer (score 17):

Assuming you are using the CLF format string, I would run `goaccess` with `-c` and then choose `NCSA Combined Log Format` from the config menu.

[image]

`"$time_local"` in nginx is replaced with `"23/Aug/2010:03:50:59 +0000"` so adding `date_format %d/%b/%Y` to your ~/.goaccessrc should do it.

**Update 1**:

Installing v0.5 from source

1. `Download` the [latest version](http://goaccess.io/download)
2. `tar -xzvf goaccess-0.5.tar.gz`
3. `cd goaccess-0.5/`
4. `./configure --enable-utf8`
5. `make`
6. `sudo make install`
7. `goaccess -a -c /var/log/apache2/access.log`

   Note: If you have it installed already, then you may only need to do step 7 prior to using `zcat`

Comment: `188.3.88.98 - - [17/Sep/2012:07:13:08 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2909 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/21.0.1180.89 Safari/537.1"`

Comment: @husnu see my answer, that should do it.

Comment: the format string is CLF. but when i run goaccess with `-c` i can't see a screen like you were send. i'm using version 0.5, please check the goaccess version. Additionally, i was installed goaccess with `sudo apt-get install goaccess` command after updating the /etc/apt/sources.list. Can you post your installation and run commands like me?

Comment: thanks for your answer. your last update not working for me. but, I think I found the root cause, when I ran the `configure`, it gave me this error: `configure: error:*** glib2 not found!`. I think, an update or installing glib2 will resolve my problems.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want to use the global options use `--no-global-config` option with goaccess.
I am using this to process my log files on a day by day basis:

```
grep --color=auto `date +"%d/%b"` /var/log/nginx/sitename.access.log | goaccess --no-global-config > report.html
```

goaccess version: 0.8

Answer (score 3):

I met the same problem with you!
Configuration file path is correct " /etc/goaccess.conf "
try to do this

```
    echo "date_format %d/%b/%Y
> log_format %h %^[%d:%^] “%r” %s %b “%R” “%u” %T
> time_format %H:%M:%S" >> /etc/goaccess.conf
```

and try again,I wish you success