# How to monitor nginx error logs with Goaccess?

Tags: nginx, error-log, goaccess

Most goaccess examples are for monitoring access logs. I want to monitor **error** logs with goaceess.

My error logs are of the following format:

```
2020/02/05 09:23:08 [crit] 9711#9711: *6 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:1420918C:SSL routines:tls_early_post_process_client_hello:version too low) while SSL handshaking, client: X.X.X.X, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2020/02/05 09:38:21 [error] 10106#10106: *3 directory index of "/var/www/example/public_html/" is forbidden, client: 162.158.166.216, server: example.com, request: "GET /nginx-reports/ HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com"
```

Right now I am using the following log format:

```
log-format %d %t %^, client: %h, server: %^, request: "%r", host: "%v"
```

However, the goaccess report is not generating a useful output. I would like to see the details of each type of error in the report.

Answer (score 1):

In my server this is the working Regexp

```
log-format %d %t %^, client: %h, server: %^, request: "%r", host: "%v", referrer: "%R"
```

Answer (score 0):

nginx 1.18, GoAccess - 1.4, assuming `locale` en_US.UTF-8

https://goaccess.io/man#examples

### For `access.log`

```
log_format %h %^[%d:%^] "%r" %s %b "%R" "%u" %T
date_format %d/%b/%Y
time_format %H:%M:%S
```

On `/etc/goaccess.conf` (system-wide) or `~/.goaccessrc` (user-wide)

Or in one line and with `'%T'`:

```
goaccess access.log --log-format='%h %^[%d:%^] "%r" %s %b "%R" "%u" %T' --date-format='%d/%b/%Y' --time-format=%T
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12556126/4970442).

[Or just](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39240021/4970442)

```
goaccess access.log --log-format=COMBINED
```

### For `error.log`

```
goaccess error.log --log-format='%d %t %^"%^" %^ %^: %h, %^: %v, %^: "%r" %^' --date-format=%Y/%m/%d --time-format=%T
```

[Source](https://github.com/allinurl/goaccess/issues/1635#issuecomment-1403014489).